# Support vector machine overfitting my data

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, svm, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to make predictions for the iris dataset. I have decided to use svms for this purpose. But, it gives me an accuracy 1.0. Is it a case of overfitting or is it because the model is very good? Here is my code.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
svm_model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1,gamma='auto')
svm_model.fit(X_train,y_train)
predictions = svm_model.predict(X_test)
accuracy_score(predictions, y_test)
```

Here, accuracy_score returns a value of 1. Please help me. I am a beginner in machine learning.

Comment: Try to use cross validation using  cross_val_score. You could use leave one out cross validation to see if the accuracy changes

Comment: Please see the example that I just posted. It's the same code but using cross validation this time. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `cross validation`:

Example:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

#load iris data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
Y = iris.target

#build the model
svm_model = SVC( kernel ='linear', C = 1, gamma = 'auto',random_state = 0 )

#create the Cross validation object
loo = LeaveOneOut()

#calculate cross validated (leave one out) accuracy score
scores = cross_val_score(svm_model, X,Y, cv = loo, scoring='accuracy')

print( scores.mean() )
```

Result (the mean accuracy of the 150 folds since we used leave-one-out):

```
0.97999999999999998
```

Bottom line:

Cross validation (especially `LeaveOneOut`) is a good way to avoid overfitting and to get robust results.

Answer (score 2):

The iris dataset is not a particularly difficult one from where to get good results. However, you are right not trusting a 100% classification accuracy model. In your example, the problem is that the 30 test points are all correctly well classified. But that doesn't mean that your model is able to generalise well for all new data instances. Just try and change the `test_size` to 0.3 and the results are no longer 100% (it goes down to 97.78%).

The best way to guarantee robustness and avoid overfitting is using cross validation. An example on how to do this easily from your example:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score


iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :4]  
y = iris.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

svm_model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1, gamma='auto')
scores = cross_val_score(svm_model, iris.data, iris.target, cv=10) #10 fold cross validation
```

Here `cross_val_score` uses different parts of the dataset as testing data iteratively (cross validation) while keeping all your previous parameters. If you check `score` you will see that the 10 accuracies calculated now range from 87.87% to 100%. To report the final model performance you can for example use the mean of the scored values.

Hope this helps and good luck! :)